# Orion Context Explorer - no examples access

Tags: php, fiware-orion

I recently tried to set up Orion Context Explorer using this repo:

https://github.com/VM9/orion-explorer-php-frame-work

It starts pretty well, however I can not gain access to examples. Without them it's really challenging to do something. I can go to localhost:7000, add some entities and it does not make any difference, however if I want to go to .../examples, server says in terminal *[404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory*. Same problem occurs if I start it on 8000 port as in github documentation.

Comment: Not sure if Orion Context Explorer is still active/update... I hope @LeonanCarvalho could have a look and provide feeeback.

Comment: Still no solution for this. Is there anyone on stack who could help or I need to contact directly fiware support?

Comment: Have you tried to create an issue about this in the orion-explorer-php-frame-work at Github? Maybe that could help the authors of the software get aware of your question. Hint: include a link to the question in SOF in the issue body, for linking purposes.

Comment: The point that the framework is in is ok for our current need, as new features come up we update the repository.
We would like very much community involvement to mature the library.
I will look closely at the issue and will answer both here and there.

Comment: Mr @LeonanCarvalho I asked for some update in github thread. Maybe there is a way of figuring this out by uploading/making some materials that are easily accessible for now as long as the situation won't be resolved?